# Imprime letras, no las palabras separadas por coma

Tags: python-3.x, csv

Estoy intentando leer un archivo CSV en Python con el siguiente código:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv

with open('DataCSV.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for line in csv_file:

        print(line[0])
```

El archivo DataCSV está separado por comas y contiene la siguiente información:

> Planta,Ficha,Kilometros
> Planta 3,F-2,3366

Cuando corro el archivo, en vez de imprimir el primer valor separado por coma, imprime la primera letra. En este caso: "P", dos veces, cuando debería imprimir: "Planta" y "Planta 3".

Si cambio: `print(line[1])`, imprime: "l", dos veces. En vez de: "Ficha" y "F-2".

Es como si leyera y separara los datos por letra, en vez de separarlos por coma.

Comment: y si haces `print(line)` que obtienes??

Comment: Hola. Tienes que cambiar `in csv_file` a `in csv_reader` en el bucle. Sino no estarás leyendo el contenido del .csv cargado en listas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es `for line in csv_reader:` Asi como lo tienes estás iterando directo en el archivo csv como si fuera un txt en vez del objeto csv.

```
with open('DataCSV.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line[0])
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Adrián y Aeportugal. Esa era la solución.